# How to remove key of a Map and covert to a List - Java

Tags: java, dictionary

In the given response, in 'reactions' property, it is a Map of Reaction Id and and Respondants to a certain comment ( Map<String,ReactionRespondants>). I need to convert this 'reactions' property to a list with in the response object by removing the key of the map. Final goal is, 'reactions' property should be a list of type ReactionRespondants. Thank you all for your effort in this :)

Given Response,

```
           "commentId": "fcbb8172-90e7-41d1-818e-e592cf4f1fbe",
           "content": "<p>New Comment</p>",
           "commenter": "138bbb3d-02ed-4d72-9a03-7e8cdfe89eff",
           "commenterFistName": "Trent",
           "commenterLatName": "Greenwood",
           "commentedAt": "2020-07-14T05:59:39.000+0000",
           "reactions": {
               "&#128077;": {
                   "reactionId": "&#128077;",
                   "respondants": [
                       {
                           "reactionId": "&#128077;",
                           "responderId": "138bbb3d-02ed-4d72-9a03-7e8cdfe89eff",
                           "responderFirstName": "James"
                       },
                       {
                           "reactionId": "&#128077;",
                           "responderId": "148bbb3d-02ed-4d72-9a03-7e8cdfe89eff",
                           "responderFirstName": "Milner"
                       }
                   ]
               },
             "&#139022;": {
                   "reactionId": "&#139022;",
                   "respondants": [
                       {
                           "reactionId": "&#139022;",
                           "responderId": "b925d3b9-1ae6-4d58-aa1e-008c76956547",
                           "responderFirstName": "Andrew"
                       },
                       {
                           "reactionId": "&#139022;",
                           "responderId": "fcbb8172-90e7-41d1-818e-e592cf4f1fbe",
                           "responderFirstName": "Mark"
                       }
                   ]
               }

           }
       }
```

Expected Response:

```
{
            "commentId": "fcbb8172-90e7-41d1-818e-e592cf4f1fbe",
            "content": "<p>New Comment</p>",
            "commenter": "138bbb3d-02ed-4d72-9a03-7e8cdfe89eff",
            "commenterFistName": "Trent",
            "commenterLatName": "Greenwood",
            "commentedAt": "2020-07-14T05:59:39.000+0000",
            "reactions": [
                    {
                    "reactionId": "&#128077;",
                    "respondants": [
                        {
                            "reactionId": "&#128077;",
                            "responderId": "138bbb3d-02ed-4d72-9a03-7e8cdfe89eff",
                            "responderFirstName": "James"
                        },
                        {
                            "reactionId": "&#128077;",
                            "responderId": "148bbb3d-02ed-4d72-9a03-7e8cdfe89eff",
                            "responderFirstName": "Milner"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                 {
                    "reactionId": "&#139022;",
                    "respondants": [
                        {
                            "reactionId": "&#139022;",
                            "responderId": "b925d3b9-1ae6-4d58-aa1e-008c76956547",
                            "responderFirstName": "Andrew"
                        },
                        {
                            "reactionId": "&#139022;",
                            "responderId": "fcbb8172-90e7-41d1-818e-e592cf4f1fbe",
                            "responderFirstName": "Mark"
                        }
                    ]
                }

            ]
        }
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a coding service. You can't just dump your task in here and expect that someone will solve it for you. You need to show some attempt yourself.

Comment: @Amongalen I tried many StackOverflow examples but could find a proper solution, which is why I am posting here

Answer (score 1):

You can transform Map<String,ReactionRespondants> to Collection
using:

```java
    Map<String,ReactionRespondants> map = ...
    Collection<ReactionRespondants> collection = map.values();
```